# Redirect http to https in Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

I search across StackOverflow for similar questions, but I need something different!

I want to redirect all my website's traffic for HTTPS and without the www.
WHY? my free SSL certificate doesn't work with the 'www.' part.

If I type:

```
www.andremlsantos.com/somepage
http://www.andremlsantos.com/somepage
http://andremlsantos.com/somepage
https://andremlsantos.com/somepage
```

I want to redirect to:

```
https://andremlsantos.com/somepage
```

My `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|subdomain|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
Options -Indexes

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If free certificate is *Let's Encrypt* you can also extend certificate to `www` subdomain. But from SEO point of view it is better to concentrate traffic to just one of those.
For wanted redirection I think [Gumbo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347183/force-non-www-and-https-via-htaccess#answer-6347222) answer can be helpful. For more useful `.htaccess` snippets [check this page](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess).

Comment: But I extended to www